# MySQL: Help changing the column names in this query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm getting the wrong kind of column names from this query ... for example, I'm getting the column name `meta_value` for the "resource_email" and the "resource_phone" cells... they both have the column name of `meta_value`

```
SET @centerLat = '48.428289';
SET @centerLng = '-123.380585';

SELECT wp_posts.*, resource_email.meta_value, resource_phone.meta_value,
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @centerLat ) ) * cos( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( lng.meta_value ) - radians(@centerLng) ) + sin( radians( @centerLat ) ) * sin( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distance

FROM wp_posts

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat 
    ON lat.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        AND lat.meta_key = 'bid_resource_lat'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lng 
    ON lng.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        AND lng.meta_key = 'bid_resource_lng'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS resource_email 
    ON resource_email.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        AND resource_email.meta_key = 'bid_resource_primary_email'

LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS resource_phone 
    ON resource_phone.post_id = wp_posts.id 
        AND resource_phone.meta_key = 'bid_resource_primary_phone'

HAVING distance < 5
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Not sure how I need to change this query in order to get the column names I really need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AS`:

```
SELECT wp_posts.*,
  resource_email.meta_value AS resource_email,
  resource_phone.meta_value AS resource_phone,
  ...
FROM ...
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS resource_email ...
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS resource_phone ...
```

The "cells" you mention are actually tables (table aliases, to be exact)

If the database does not accept column aliases equal to table aliases, you need to use different table aliases (or different column names).

Comment: Learning all the time ... I have no idea you could use `AS` at that point.

Comment: @dcolumbus you have already used an alias for the calculated column. You can do the same for ordinary columns.